Can I use the Universal set in my Set Theory proof?
I know that "THE" Universal set does not exists, that all sets exists relative to other sets. That because of the Russel Paradox we cannot naively create a set only by arbitrary properties of its elements, we must take the elements that sattisfies the properties from another well known set.
The thing is that I'm proving something and at some point I got to something that looks like $A\cap(B\cup B^c)$.
Can I say that $(B\cup B^c) = \Omega$ with $\Omega$ the universal set? ($B^c$ is the complement of $B$)
If that is the case then I can simply do
\begin{align}
&A\cap(B\cup B^c)\\
\iff& A\cap \Omega\\
\iff& A
\end{align}
But I'm afraid from the many proofs that the Universal set does not exist.
Nonetheless I believe that what does not exist is the Absolute Universal set. What I mean is that for a set (or class?) of sets, there is a Relative Universal Set that contains all possible sets derived from them...
I just want to know how to justify the above manipulation...
P.S. I'm proving that the cardinality of a Power set is 2 to the power of its set cardinality.
Edit:
I'm in a part of the proof where I want to prove:
if $\  a \in x   \ \text{and }  y = x \backslash \{a\} \implies x = y \cup \{a\}$
\begin{align*}
& \ y \cup \{a\} \\
\iff \ &(x \backslash \{a\}) \cup \{a\} \\ 
\iff \ &(x \cap \{a\}^c)\cup\{a\} \ \text{<--- Here I'm using a definition for set difference}  \\ 
\iff \ &(x \cup \{a\}) \cap (\{a\}^c \cup \{a\})  \\
\iff \ &(x \cup \{a\}) \cap \Omega \ \text{ < -----I used $\Omega$ as Universal set}\\
\iff \ &x \cup \{a\}\\
\iff \ & x \ ( \text{because } a \in x \iff \{a\} \subseteq x )\\
\\
\therefore\ & x = y \cup \{a\} 
\end{align*}

It's good that you included the note about what you're trying to solve, but what would be better is if you wrote down how you're trying to solve it and how you got to the point you have the question about.

Without a universal set $B^c$ makes no sense. So you need to explain more carefully how you got to this point. (I've no idea why you'd need complements to prove the cardinality of power set thingie.)

What do you mean by $B^c$?

I added an Edit to the question  showing the controversial proof.

$B^c$ is the complement of B

As people have commented, one problem is that complementation is not actually a set operation, only relative complement (i.e. set difference). Otherwise we'd need to have $\emptyset^c=\Omega,$ but $\Omega$ is not a set.
So the definition of $x\setminus y$ is not $x\cap y^c$ since $y^c$ isn't a thing. The definition is $x\setminus y:=\{z\in x: z\notin y\}.$
To show $x=(x\setminus\{a\})\cup\{a\},$ show that $x\subseteq(x\setminus\{a\})\cup\{a\}$ and $(x\setminus\{a\})\cup\{a\}\subseteq x.$
For the first direction, assume $z\in x.$ If $z\in \{a\}$, then $z\in(x\setminus\{a\})\cup\{a\}$ by the defintion of $\cup$. If not, then $z\in x$ and $z\notin\{a\},$ which by definition means $z\in x\setminus\{a\},$ so again, $z\in(x\setminus\{a\})\cup\{a\}.$
For the other direction, if $z\in(x\setminus\{a\})\cup\{a\}$ then either $z\in x\setminus\{a\},$ in which case $z\in x,$ or $z\in \{a\},$ in which case $z= a\in x$.
Note you can still use absolute complementation in situations where you are dealing only with a collection of subsets of a given set (which can be called a "universal set" for the given context and “absolute complementation” just means difference with this set). I suspect that may be the case here, but I'm not sure where this fits in to the proof of $|P(A)|= 2^{|A|},$ which I would recommend proving by establishing a one-to-one correspondence between a subset $B\subseteq A$ and its indicator function $1_B: A\to 2$ where $1_B(x) = 1$ if $x\in B,$ else $0,$ with an inverse corresponence of $f:A\to 2$ to the subset $B_f = \{x\in A: f(x)=1\}.$

I just wanted to avoid proving double contention of the sets, but seems the only right way to do it. Also, I wanted to prove that ${ X : X\subseteq A $ and  $a \in X} = {b \cup {a} : b \in {X : X \subseteq A $ and  $a \not\in X}}`$ and proceed to define a function and prove bijection on it. That's where the $y \cup {a}$ came from.

@Alejo I should also say it’s not, strictly speaking, “wrong” to consider proper classes and intersections of proper classes with sets and so forth, and as such your approach isn’t wrong per se. It just requires a bit more care to understand fully what’s going on there, and sticking to sets is simpler in that sense.

I was about to define the universal set relative to the exercise as the union of all the sets in the problem union the sets per sé or something like that (I still can't see it well, but something like the minimal set that contains all the sets used in the proof(?)). But I didn't know if that was acceptable to do, because it might have required the acceptance of the reader, and I'm not an authority to define such an axiom, I felt like arrogant or something (?).

Just to be slightly annoying and technical, while $y^c$ is not a set, one can still define it as a proper class using ${a\mid a\notin y}$, and in that case, $x\cap y^c={a\in x\mid a\notin y}$. So while the operation $y\mapsto y^c$ is not "well-defined" and can be added to an expanded language, it still, in a vague way, makes sense. Nevertheless, it is absolutely correct that thinking about this in terms of $x\setminus y$ is preferable.

@AsafKaragila Yes I should have made a point of that in the post, but added something to that effect in my previous comment to instead
